# Recursion: $f(n+1)=-2f(n)$

Tags: recursion

Given the function defined recursively as:

$f(n+1)=-2f(n)$

$f(0)=3$

How can I find $f(5)$ using the recursion?

Comment: Have you tried to solve for $f(1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One has recursively
$$
f(5)=-2\times f(4)=-2\times (-2) \times f(3)= \cdots.
$$
Hope you can finish it.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
if
$f(n+1) = af(n)$,
then,
for any $k \ge 0$,
we have
$f(n+k)
=a^k f(n)$.

Setting
$n=0$,
$f(k) = a^kf(0)$.

In your case
$a=-2$
and
$f(0) = 3$
so
$f(k)=3(-2)^k$.

If $k=5$,
$f(5)
=3(-2)^5
=-3\cdot 32
=-96
$.

Answer (score 0):

You know $f(0) =3$, now us this and apply $f(n+1) = -2f(n)$ to find f(1).

i.e. $f(1) = f(0+1) = -2f(0) = -2(3) = -6$.

repeat this process using $f(2) = f(1+1)$ and so on until you get to

$f(5) = f(4+1) = -2f(4)$

Comment: So I did as you told me and it's $f(5)=-96$

Comment: As you start not from 5 but from 0 it isn't recursion, is it?

Comment: @Pavel I believe you are correct. While the function is define recursively I did not solve it using recursion. Which is the repeated application of the recursive definition until we get f(5) in terms of f(0).  Marty Cohen has the correct answer below.